# numpy: concat/append one additional column to the original matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix `X_test` and a series `y_test`, their dimensions are:

```
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

(5, 9)
(5,)
```

I then tried to add `y_test` as the last column of `X_test` like below:

```
np.concatenate((X_test, y_test), axis = 1)
```

but got the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-2edea4d89805> in <module>()
     24 
---> 25 print(np.concatenate((X_test, y_test), axis = 1))

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

---

I also tried:

```
np.append((X_test, y_test), 1)
```

but also got errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-f3d5e5ec7978> in <module>()

---> 26 print(np.append((X_test, y_test), 1))

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in append(arr, values, axis)
   5139 
   5140     """
-> 5141     arr = asanyarray(arr)
   5142     if axis is None:
   5143         if arr.ndim != 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asanyarray(a, dtype, order)
    581 
    582     """
--> 583     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
    584 
    585 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,9) into shape (5)
```

What did I miss here? What should be the correct way to add `y_test` as the last column of matrix `X_test`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to give `y_test` a new dimension.  Do you know about `reshape` or `np.newaxis`?

```
In [280]: X = np.ones((5,9))
In [281]: y = np.ones((5,))
In [282]: np.concatenate((X, y), axis=1)
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
In [283]: y.reshape(5,1)
Out[283]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])

In [285]: np.concatenate((X,y.reshape(5,1)),1).shape
Out[285]: (5, 10)
In [287]: np.concatenate((X,y[:,None]),1).shape
Out[287]: (5, 10)
```

`np.column_stack` does the same adjustment, but it's good to know how to work with `concatenate` directly. Understanding and changing the dimensions of arrays is central to productive `numpy` work.

Answer (score 1):

np.concatenate will work if you change your y_test to (5,1) instead of (5,)

do

```
y_test = np.array([y_test])
np.concatenate((X_test, y_test), axis = 1)
```

if that does not work then try transposing your arrays with .T to get the axis in the correct location.

Comment: Your `y_test` modification amounts to `y_test[None,:]`, adding a new dimension at the start, making it `(1,5)`.